# Is it possible in a Cordova/Ionic-app to bind a template to a controller without state?

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic-app.
On one of my templates i have a div in which i want to load one of my other templates.

The loading was programmed in controllers.js like that:

```
    var panel_dynamic = document.getElementById('panel_dynamic');
    if (panel_dynamic.hasChildNodes()) {
        panel_dynamic.removeChild(panel_dynamic.childNodes[0]);
    }
    var line = document.createElement("div");
    if(item.id == 9999)
    {
        $.get("templates\\type-of-test.html?Param=" + item.id, function (response) {
            line.innerHTML = response;
        });
        panel_dynamic.appendChild(line);
    }
```

As You can see i open the template "type-of-test.html" with a parameter inside a div called "panel_dynamic".
Unfortunately in this case it's not possible to connect my template with it's controller by a state (defined in app.js).
I tried to use ng-controller in my template "type-of-test.html" like that but no success:

```
<ion-view view-title="Type of test" ng-controller="TypeOfTestCtrl">
    <ion-content class="padding has-header">
```

How can i create the reference between my template and the controller?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the Model. as you described this might solve your Problem: 
Usage :

```
<script id="my-modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
<ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar>
      <h1 class="title">My Modal title</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      Hello!
    </ion-content>
  </ion-modal-view>
</script>
```

JavaScript :

```
angular.module('testApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('MyController', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };
  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };
  // Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $scope.modal.remove();
  });
  // Execute action on hide modal
  $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function() {
    // Execute action
  });
  // Execute action on remove modal
  $scope.$on('modal.removed', function() {
    // Execute action
  });
});
```

Or you can refer [this link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. For that you need to use modal.

For opening modal -

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/data.html', { 
   id:'data',
   scope: $scope,
   animation: 'none',
   backdropClickToClose: false
}).then(function(modal) {
   $scope.modal = modal;
   $scope.modal.show();
});
```

Note: either you need to specify controller in html or you can use controller from which you have opened this modal.

Comment: Sorry, i don't want to open a modal window, but a template inside a template (including the controller).